# Is there a published roadmap for Trello development?

Tags: trello

The Trello team is pretty open about what they're working on on the [Trello Development Board](http://trello.com/dev). But there doesn't seem to be a lot of guidance on what features from the Ideas column are going to be implemented or when they're planned for release.

Is there a published roadmap of what they're intending to implement?

Comment: Can you explain what you're looking for that isn't covered in the "Next Up" and "In Progress" lists on the Trello Development Board? You might want to review the "What can you expect from this board?" card here: https://trello.com/c/NIRpzVDM

Answer (score 3):

At Fog Creek Software, we're very careful about saying publicly what we're planning for the future. Is this because we are delicate geniuses who must not be held accountable to our fans and users?

No.

We hate to be in the position of making promises that we find out later on we can't keep. Breaking promises is a recipe for eroding trust.

[Software is a tricky business](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVvaKjp4jrA). Too often, after having embarked upon solving a problem, we later find out that two things we'd like to do are in direct conflict. We might also find that the challenges involved in implementing a given feature are too great given the possible benefit; our time might be better-used elsewhere. And all that assumes that our product operates in some sort of vacuum. While we were busy implementing one feature, a shift might have happened to make a different feature the right one to do next.

Without public promises, we get through these adjustments and difficult decisions as best we can. It's the nature of the business. When we make public promises, though, we have to decide which segment of our users we have to disappoint. We have to explain our decision, and end up alienating our user base.

We'd rather ask our users to live with same uncertainties that we operate under than give them a false sense of certainty that we might later have to destroy.